# Is it safe to call the ContinueWith method on a TaskCompletionSource.Task (that has had it's .SetResult called)?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, task-parallel-library

Is it safe to use the `ContinueWith(...)` method on a `TaskCompletionSource.Task` if the `TaskCompletionSource.SetResult(...)` has already been called?

This basic code will hopefully help to frame the question:

```
// this was written inside the question box, please excuse any silly errors and lack of error checking (I'm not near VS right now)...

private WebClient _webClient = new WebClient();

public Task<string> GetExamplePage() {

    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();

    web.DownloadStringCompleted += (s, ea) => tcs.SetResult(ea.Result);

    web.DownloadStringAsync(new URI(@"http://www.example.com/example.html"));

    return tcs.task;
}

public void ProcessExamplePage() {
    
    var task = GetExamplePage();

    Thread.Sleep(1000);

    task.ContinueWith(t => Console.WriteLine(t.Result)); // *line in question*
}
```

Will the `Console.WriteLine(...)` execute if the `WebClient.DownloadStringCompleted` event has already fired before the `task.ContinueWith` is set?

MSDN has this to say ([Task.ContinueWith](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270696.aspx)):

> Task.ContinueWith Method
>
> The returned Task will not be scheduled for execution until the
> current task has completed, whether it completes due to running to
> completion successfully, faulting due to an unhandled exception, or
> exiting out early due to being canceled.

Unfortunately that doesn't mention what happens if this method is called and the task has already completed.

Thank you in advance for any information you can provide! :)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Yes this should be fine, ContinueWith checks if the previous task completed or not, if so it will immediately queue up the continuation.

Comment: Will this start a new asynchronous operation or will this just continue synchronously? As the ``TaskCompletionSource`` didn't start an asynchronous operation.

Comment: Nice. A reference to documentation regarding this would be great.

Comment: @annemartijn It depends on whether the original task (or continuation) specifies `TaskCreationOptions​.​RunContinuationsAsynchronously` (or `TaskContinuationOptions​.​Run​Continuations​Asynchronously`)​--​these apply to their *continuations* only​--​and/or whether the continuation specifies the `TaskContinuationOptions​.​ExecuteSynchronously` (this applies to a continuation itself).

Answer (score 1):

If the specified task has already completed by the time ContinueWith is called, the synchronous continuation will run on the thread calling ContinueWith. 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321576(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Wrong. This text is for Example that is explicit in that by specifying TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously