# Get reference of continuewith task when using Task.Run

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

Assuming i have

```
Task t1 = Task.Run(() =>
{
    // do something
}).ContinueWith((t) => {
    int x;
});
```

I think t1 is the reference of the ContinuteWith Task. How can i get a reference to the first task? Is it possible at all?

Is there a shortcut to this or do i have to create the Task with new and then append the continuewith separately?

Comment: You seem to be asking different questions in your question title and your question text...

Comment: come on you know what i mean. how to get the other reference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @toddmo mentioned, to get the both references of the primary `Task` and it's continuation you may like to do something like this:

```
Task t1 = Task.Run(() => {
    // do something
});
Task t1Continuation = t1.ContinueWith((t) => {
    int x;
});
```

AFAIK there is no convenience method to achieve this in a one-liner fashion. Also, keep in mind that the object received in the ContinueWith lambda, is the first task, where you can check it's [results](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321468(v=vs.110).aspx) or if there where any [errors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.exception(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Isn't the problem here that t1 could be already finished before i define t1Continuation? And if so, would t1Continuation still run?

Comment: Yes, you're right, `t1` can finish before the `t1.ContinueWith` call, but bear in mind that ContinueWith checks if the _Task_ has already finished. If it does, then [runs the method provided immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7466040/2740778). So, you can still call `t1.ContinueWith` whether the first _Task_ finished or not.

Answer (score 0):

Declare t1 separately

Put the first leg in parentheses. Remove "Task" at the beginning

Assign the whole thing to t2